# .Net Entity Framework SaveChanges is adding without add method

Tags: entity-framework, savechanges

I'm new to the entity framework and I'm really confused about how savechanges works.  There's probably a lot of code in my example which could be improved, but here's the problem I'm having.

The user enters a bunch of picks.  I make sure the user hasn't already entered those picks.
Then I add the picks to the database.

```
       var db = new myModel()
       var predictionArray = ticker.Substring(1).Split(','); // Get rid of the initial comma.

        var user = Membership.GetUser();
        var userId = Convert.ToInt32(user.ProviderUserKey);

        // Get the member with all his predictions for today.
        var memberQuery = (from member in db.Members
                         where member.user_id == userId
                         select new
                                    {
                                        member,
                                        predictions = from p in member.Predictions
                                                     where p.start_date == null
                                                     select p

                                    }).First();

        // Load all the company ids.
        foreach (var prediction in memberQuery.predictions)
        {
            prediction.CompanyReference.Load();
        }

 var picks = from prediction in predictionArray
                          let data = prediction.Split(':')
                          let companyTicker = data[0]
                          where !(from i in memberQuery.predictions
                                 select i.Company.ticker).Contains(companyTicker)
                          select new Prediction
                          {
                              Member = memberQuery.member,
                              Company = db.Companies.Where(c => c.ticker == companyTicker).First(),
                              is_up = data[1] == "up",  // This turns up and down into true and false.
                          };


    // Save the records to the database.
    // HERE'S THE PART I DON'T UNDERSTAND.
    // This saves the records, even though I don't have db.AddToPredictions(pick) 
            foreach (var pick in picks)
            {
                    db.SaveChanges();
            }

// This does not save records when the db.SaveChanges outside of a loop of picks.
 db.SaveChanges();
 foreach (var pick in picks)
            {

            }

// This saves records,  but it will insert all the picks exactly once no matter how many picks you have.  
//The fact you're skipping a pick makes no difference in what gets inserted.
            var counter = 1;
            foreach (var pick in picks)
            {
                if (counter == 2)
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                counter++;
            }
```

I've tested and the SaveChanges doesn't even have to be in the loop. 
The below code works, too.

```
foreach (var pick in picks)
            {
                   break;
            }

db.SaveChanges()
```

There's obviously something going on with the context I don't understand.  I'm guessing I've somehow loaded my new picks as pending changes, but even if that's true I don't understand I have to loop over them to save changes.

### Can someone explain this to me?

Here's updated working code based on Craig's responses: 
1) Remove the Type then loop over the results and populate new objects.

```
var  picks = (from prediction in predictionArray
                        let data = prediction.Split(':')
                        let companyTicker = data[0]
                        where !(from i in memberQuery.predictions
                                select i.Company.ticker).Contains(companyTicker)
                        select new //NO TYPE HERE
                        {
                            Member = memberQuery.member,
                            Company = db.Companies.Where(c => c.ticker == companyTicker).First(),
                            is_up = data[1] == "up",  // This turns up and down into true and false.
                        }).ToList();

            foreach (var prediction in picks)
            {
              if (includePrediction)
               {
                var p = new Prediction{
                  Member = prediction.Member,
                  Company = prediction.Company,
                  is_up = prediction.is_up
                 };
                db.AddToPredictions(p);
                }
            }
```

2) Or if I don't want the predictions to be saved, I can detach the predictions.

```
foreach (var prediction in picks) {
                  if  (excludePrediction)
                  {
                      db.Detach(prediction)
                   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is here:

```
                      select new Prediction
                      {
                          Member = memberQuery.member,
```

These lines will (once the `IEnumerable` is iterated; LINQ is lazy) :

1. Instantiate a new `Prediction`
2. Associate that `Prediction` with an existing `Member`, *which is attached to `db`.

Associating an instance of an entity with an attached entity *automatically* adds that entity to the context of the associated, attached entity.

So as soon as you start iterating over `predictionArray`, the code above executes and you have a new entity in your context.

Comment: I think I'm starting to grasp this.  How do I detach the predictions if I want to? 

I also found this (for anyone else reading this) which explains the deferred execution you mentioned which helped me understand why I needed to call my picks variable before I saved. I've replaced the loop with the ToList() command.
 
http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/01/08/entity-framework-first-steps/

Comment: You detach with Context.Detach. But you can also just project onto an anonymous type (or other POCO) instead of onto a new entity instance.

Comment: Thanks, Craig.  I've updated my question based on your responses.  This was a big help.